# How to create QtWebApp application

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qtwebapp

I'm trying to use `QtWebApp` to create a simple web app server, but it shows some error that i could not figure how to fix, any hint how to fix this?

here's what i've done:

= downloading `QtWebApp-src.zip` from http://stefanfrings.de/qtwebapp/

= compiling `QtWebApp` using `qmake` and `make`, completed successfully

= create a new `qwtest.pro`, containing:

```
QT       += core network
QT       -= gui
TARGET   = qwtest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

= create source file `main.cpp`, containing:

```
#include "../v1.3.2 2014-01-08/lib/bfHttpServer/src/httplistener.h"
#include <QtCore>

class MyController: public HttpRequestHandler {
  private:
    QCoreApplication *app;
  public:
    MyController(QCoreApplication *app) : app(app) {}
    void service(HttpRequest& request, HttpResponse& response);
};

void MyController::service(HttpRequest& request, HttpResponse& response) {
    QByteArray path=request.getPath();
    QByteArray username=request.getParameter("username");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
    response.setCookie(HttpCookie("myCookie","any value",600));
    response.write("<html><body>");
    response.write("Hello ");
    response.write(username);
    response.write("</body></html>");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication* app=new QCoreApplication(argc,argv);    
    QSettings* settings=new QSettings("configfile.ini",QSettings::IniFormat,app);
    MyController* controller=new MyController(app);
    HttpListener* listener=new HttpListener(settings,controller,app);    
    return app->exec();
}
```

= compiling using `qmake` and `make`

```
/home/foo/qtwebapp/build-QtWebApp-Desktop-Debug/../v1.3.2 2014-01-08/src/main.cpp:66: undefined reference to `Startup::Startup(int, char**)'
/home/foo/qtwebapp/build-QtWebApp-Desktop-Debug/../v1.3.2 2014-01-08/src/main.cpp:67: undefined reference to `QtServiceBase::exec()'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE[_ZTV9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE]+0x28): undefined reference to `QtServiceBase::stop()'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE[_ZTV9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE]+0x30): undefined reference to `QtServiceBase::pause()'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE[_ZTV9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE]+0x38): undefined reference to `QtServiceBase::resume()'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE[_ZTV9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE]+0x40): undefined reference to `QtServiceBase::processCommand(int)'
main.o: In function `Startup::~Startup()':
/home/foo/qtwebapp/build-QtWebApp-Desktop-Debug/../v1.3.2 2014-01-08/src/startup.h:16: undefined reference to `vtable for Startup'
main.o: In function `QtService<QCoreApplication>::~QtService()':
/home/foo/qtwebapp/build-QtWebApp-Desktop-Debug/../v1.3.2 2014-01-08/lib/qtservice/src/qtservice.h:170: undefined reference to `QtServiceBase::~QtServiceBase()'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE[_ZTI9QtServiceI16QCoreApplicationE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for QtServiceBase'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:182: recipe for target 'qwtest' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the libs, this what i should add on the `qwtest.pro` file

```
LIBS += /home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/http*.o \
/home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/moc_*.o \
/home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/log*.o \
/home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/f*.o \
/home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/template*.o \
/home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/du*.o \
/home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/request*.o \
/home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/session*.o \
/home/foo/qtwebapp/qwtest/static*.o
```

Comment: you shouldn't do this like that!

Comment: is that another project? If it is, then you need to create library and link with that library.

Comment: doesn't "create library" means create files with `.o` extension?

Comment: no it doesn't. It's either static library (.a on Linux, .lib on Windows and .a on Mac OS X) or dynamic library (.so on Linux, .dll on Windows and .dylib on Mac OS X)

Comment: could you refer me some reference about this part?

Answer (score 1):

Your project file must include the sources of the bfHttpServer classes. Take a look at the project file that comes with the QtWebapp example, there you see how to include them.

```
include(lib/bfHttpServer/src/bfHttpServer.pri)
```

Answer (score 1):

> main.cpp:66: undefined reference to `Startup::Startup(int, char**)'

The main.cpp file that you compiled uses the Startup class from the example application. But the main.cpp that you posted above does not.

I assume you are compiling the wrong directory. Or maybe you just have to call qmake to update some files.