# Chrome, Chromium, Firefox requesting page twice on QtWebApp

Tags: c++, qt, google-chrome, firefox, qtwebapp

I'm trying to create a simple web app server using `QtWebApp`, but Chrome, Firefox and chromium always requesting the page twice

```
HttpListener: Listening on port 8084
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): constructed
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): constructed
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): thread started
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): handle new connection
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): received request
request start --> with chrome/firefox/chromium
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): thread started
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): handle new connection
request end
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): received request
request start --> i'm not refreshing the page but this appear
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): read timeout occured
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): disconnected
request end
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): read timeout occured
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): disconnected
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): thread stopped
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): destroyed
HttpConnectionHandlerPool: Removed connection handler (0x6436e0), pool size is now 1
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): handle new connection
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): received request
request start --> when using curl
request end
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): disconnected
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): disconnected
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): read timeout occured
HttpConnectionHandler (0x642770): disconnected
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): thread stopped
HttpConnectionHandler (0x6436e0): destroyed
```

my response from curl was just:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8084
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<html><body>-4417809641995</body></html>
```

while on the Chrome Developer Tools > Network tab, it seen only requested once.

the source: [How to create QtWebApp application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623960/how-to-create-qtwebapp-application)

Is this browser's problem or Controller's class?

Comment: Just a random guess: do they maybe request the `/favicon.ico` in the second request?

Comment: ah yeah, that's right XD thank you very much.. 
"/favicon.ico"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Florian Sowade` said on the comment, the second request was `/favicon.ico`